# Memory Error thrown when sorting subtrings in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this program to form a set of strings ordered lexicographically from a collection of strings. the number of input strings and the strings itself is taken as input and the program is meant to lexicographically form a set containing strings and substrings from the input.

```
strst=set()
nos=input()

for i in range(0,nos):
    ele=raw_input()
    for j in range(0,len(ele),1):
        for k in range(j+1,len(ele)+1):
                strst.add(ele[j:k])

strlst=sorted(strst)

print strlst
```

Thi program stores the substrings in to a set and later sorts it keep the lexicographical order and finally prints the whole list

for eg:

```
INPUT :

2             //number of input strings
aab
aac

OUTPUT

['a', 'aa', 'aab', 'aac', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'c']
```

the program is working fine for small sized inputs but when the input size , that is the number of input strings and length of each strings increases around the range 2000 its giving an exception :

```
MemoryError thrown on line 9
```

i thk I havent optimized the code. Can the sorting be optimised?..can the size of set data structure and list be extended?

Comment: It would help if you could include 3 things. 1: An explanation of what you are trying to do, not just the code and that "it isn't working" 2: a sample input that *does* work for you 3: the output that you get after that input goes through your function.

Comment: Does it really say `MemoryError thrown on line 9`? That format looks wrong. Can you paste the actual stack trace?

Comment: This is __Python__ not C - get rid of the semicolons!

Comment: @Steve: done... i m jst a begineer in python,,cant get rid of old habbits...

Comment: @user2357112 : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run-qDtOsHpnEIYuw17QUeyx/solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    strst.add(ele[j:k]);
MemoryError
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 58, in apport_excepthook
    from cStringIO import StringIO
MemoryError

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run-qDtOsHpnEIYuw17QUeyx/solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    strst.add(ele[j:k]);

Comment: You are storing sum(1...n) = n(n+1)/2 substrings for each n-length string, so your memory usage is O(n^2) in the length of the string (discounting duplicates). If you are running into memory errors, it's probably not a question of optimization. You should consider writing your intermediate results to temporary files and then combining them later.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem redundant to state it I suspect that the reason that you are getting a memory error is that you are running out of memory.

If with 2 mostly overlapping strings of length 3 you get 8 elements then just the non-blank coverage for all the possible 3 letter = 26 + 650 + 15600 = 16276

As a quick test:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> for m in range(1, 20):
...     for i in itertools.permutations(range(26), m):
...         n+=1
...     print m, n
... 
1 26
2 676
3 16276
4 375076
5 8268676
6 174034276
```

....

Comment: I don't see how permutations are relevant here. The program is building substrings, not permutations; it should only have space requirements quadratic in the size of the input, or cubic if the substring implementation is copying the data instead of sharing it between strings.

Comment: Since it is order critical permutations give an indication of the size of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve correctly points out the problem is the number of combinations of an input string that you are string in memory.

The correct solution to this would be to use a generator function that would generate combinations of the input string.

Luckily python standard library already contains the **itertools** package that will help you achieve what you want with very less code and in a more efficient way. Given below is a sample code snippet that would produce the same output that you have shown as an example in your question:

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
x  = "aab"
y =  "aac"
x_permutation =[]
y_permutation = []

#use the combinations method within the itertools package to generate all possible combinations of a given length  for a given string

for i in xrange(1,len(x)+1):
        x_permutation = x_permutation + list(map("".join,combinations(x,i)))

for i in xrange(1,len(y)+1):
        y_permutation = y_permutation + list(map("".join, combinations(y,i)))

#if the input string is  already sorted for e.g. "ABCD" , you do not really need to call the sort.However, when we do not have this guarantee then it is better to call sort()

x_permutation.sort()
y_permutation.sort()

#merge the two lists into a set and then sort the set using the built-in **sorted()**
output_set =sorted(set (x_permutation + y_permutation))

print output_set
```

The output of the above script is : `['a', 'aa', 'aab', 'aac', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'c']`

Hopefully, this should now help you to think of solving your problem using the itertools techniques.